# Installing Heroku's Taps gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, heroku

I'm trying to use Heroku's Taps gem to get my database from their server.

When I run

```
$heroku db:pull
```

it says I need to install the Taps gem using the command:

```
sudo gem install taps
```

I run this command, and as expected, Taps says it has installed ("1 gem installed"). I'm able to run the Gem update taps command without an error after installing.

However,

> $gem list

does not show Taps as installed, and I cannot see it in the gem folder at

/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@timeline

Needless to say, I cannot run the Heroku db:pull command because of this.

I am running bundlr and RVM, I don't know if these are relevant.

I'm sure I'm doing something simple wrong...

Comment: Since you are using multiple versions of ruby i would recommend you to recheck the gem folders under each of the ruby versions . may be that you  have installed it for ruby version 1.8.2 and may be checking the gems files of 1.8.7 .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `sudo gem install taps` probably installs the gem with root permissions, and thus you can't see it as your normal user when you try to `gem list`. Have you tried installing the gem without sudo? or if you really want to find it, try `sudo gem list`.

I would suggest not installing gems with sudo though, the point of using rvm is to always have your gems bundled in a place you can access (without root) and separated conveniently with rubies/gemsets.